# JQuery Show / hide images in list one at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an list with banner images.

```
<ul id="banners">
    <li><img src="image1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), how can I have them show one at the time every few seconds?

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: It's called a slideshow, and there are thousands of plugins available, jQuery cycle comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small function that will toggle the visibility of each child `<li>` element - one at a time - every 1s

```
#banners li {
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
$('#banners li').each(function(index, value) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(value).show().siblings().hide();
    }, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

I've removed the images, as I am just giving a visual demo here - toggling the `<li>` elements.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbnnvgjw/) - simplified demo

---

To loop this, observe the following, where `time` is how long we wish to show each element...

```
var time = 1000; // 1s

function toggle() {
    $('#banners li').each(function(index, value) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(value).show().siblings().hide();
         }, time * (index + 1));
    });
}

toggle();

setInterval(toggle, $('#banners li').length * time);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z473mrx6/) - demo wrapped with `setInterval`

Answer (score 3):

Here you have an example which changes image randomly with interval of 1.5 seconds:

Html:

```
<ul id="banners">
    <li><img src="image1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#banners > li');

    var hideAllImages = function() {
        for(var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
            lis[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        }
    }

    var showImage = function(index) {
        lis[index].setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
    }

    var showRandomImage = function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * lis.length);
        hideAllImages();
        showImage(index);
    }

    showRandomImage();

    setInterval(showRandomImage, 1500);

})();
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5L5rvbb5/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will cycle through the images indefinitely if that is the idea. That way it won't just end after the third image.

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var $el = $(".s");
    $el.removeClass("s")
       .next("li")
       .addClass("s")
       .closest("ul")
       .append($el);
  },500);
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/lifozirubo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you use jquery's hide and show method. If you want to get fancy, you can do animations, like fadein or fadeout. I believe the changing requires using not jquery, but just plain javascript. I'm not sure if jquery has a shorter way, but I know for sure you can implement it with just javascript if not. You probably look into using javascripts timing facilites, along with some branching to show and hide different images, which would probably need to have special class like 'active-image' appied to whichever one you are showing. Judging by your rep, you're probably more knowledgeable in general, but I hope helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.toggle()` , recursively call `complete` callback if next element exists , else call `complete` callback on parent element first `li` child

```js
$("#banners li:first").toggle(3000, function slide() {
  $(this).toggle(3000, function() {
    $(this.nextElementSibling || this.parentElement.firstElementChild)
    .toggle(3000, slide)
  })
})
```

```css
#banners li {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="banners">
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics" />
  </li>
</ul>
```